# Библиотека парсинг с js без драйвера, есть?

Tags: javascript, python, requests

Существуют ли какие-либо библиотеки без использования драйвера (selenium)?
Библиотеки, которые будут парсинг сайты с использованием js.
Например https://dns-shop.com
Сток библиотека requests, не сможет получить код, ибо не прогружаются скрипты. И мне нужно получить цену товара с сайта, не используя драйвер браузера!

Answer (score 0):

[requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) Умеет запускать скрипты. Но в идеале такие задачи решать подругому: понять, откуда цены берутся, и парсить конкретную ссылку, например часто это делается через Json